# Start in the middle and then go up with css

Tags: css

I was wondering how I can start in the middle of a  and when a extra div is added by Jquery the container keeps the middle as starting point. So the first div starts in the middle of an absolute placed div and when the second comes in, both div's keeps the middle as starting point.

So what I have is this:

```
<div class="zoeken-absolute">
        <div class="zoeken">
          <form>
            <div class="zoeken-select">
              <div id="cat1" class="zoeken-value">Selecteer je school/opleiding</div>
              <div class="zoeken-handle"></div>
              <select class="gui-validate" id="school">
                <option>Selecteer je school/opleiding</option>
                <option value="656462">menu</option>
                <option value="653688">HBO Spaans</option>  
              </select>
            </div>

    /////// This div below becomes visible when something is selected above ////////

            <div class="zoeken-select course">
              <div id="cat2" class="zoeken-value">Selecteer je sector/locatie</div>
              <div class="zoeken-handle"></div>
              <select class="gui-validate" id="course">

              </select>
            </div>
   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

My css:

```
#index .zoeken-absolute {
  background: url("zoekenbg.png?") no-repeat scroll center top rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 220px;
  left: 500px;
  top: 75px;
  width: 400px;
  z-index: 999;
  position:absolute;
}
.zoeken-select {
  background: url("newsbg.png?") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #D7D7D7;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FAD689;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 26px;
  line-height: 26px;
  margin: 9px 0 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 238px;

}
.zoeken-select .zoeken-value {
  height: 26px;
  left: 9px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #FFFFFF;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.zoeken-select .zoeken-handle {
  background: url("zoekdd.png") no-repeat scroll -3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-left: 1px solid #8D8D8D;
  height: 26px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 25px;
}

.zoeken-select select {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#index .zoeken > form {
  margin-top:20px;
}
```

Comment: if you want all divs to be in the middle just put all of them in a div which you would put in the middle and that way when you add new div it would be in the middle because the wrapper div will be in the middle

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. Starting point for what?